# Vue.js: console warning with vue-moment with firebase dates from authentication - date updated

Tags: firebase, vue.js, momentjs, vue-component

**Moment is returning what I want...**

`Date updated: 41 minutes ago`

But I get Chrome console warning:
`` Could not build a valid `moment` object from input. ``

---

**Date coming from Firebase in this format**

dateUpdate:

`2018-10-25T17:33:24.537Z`

**profile.vue**

```
<span>Date updated: {{ dateUpdated | moment("from", "now") }}</span>
```

**Question**
How do I suppress this error?

(it seems that the Firebase date is not valid for moment.js)

**vue-moment.js**

```
  if (!input || !date.isValid()) {
    // Log a warning if moment couldn't reconcile the input. Better than throwing an error?
    console.warn('Could not build a valid `moment` object from input.');
    return input;
  }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you do:

```
<span>{{ [ dateUpdated, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS" ] | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY") }}</span>
```

See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/

The following "simple" JavaScript prints `true` in the console, using the "standard" moment.js library:

```
var sDate = "2018-10-25T17:33:24.537Z";
var mDate = moment(sDate, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS");
console.log(mDate.isValid());
```

Comment: This happens when I try that code in .vue file:`Date updated: 21 minutes ago [ "2018-10-25T19:10:37.818Z", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS" ]` - i.e. just text outputed - thanks- I'll keep trying.

Comment: Yet, it seems the syntax is correct, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment#passing-your-date

Comment: I"m just using moment.js without vue-moment, and there is no warnings now... I'll keep testing and post my solution... note, for firebase dates, I added a `Z` to `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS"` to get it to work in my timezone... it was saying 4 hours from now, until I added the `Z` - thanks.

Comment: I also forgot to add the `Z` when declaring what format the date string was coming in as, and I couldn't figure out why it was just outputting the literal string to the console instead of formatting it. Thanks for this answer!